# fancyhdr package: Not Displaying header and footer

Tags: fancyhdr

Can anyone help me see why the `fancyhdr` package fails to display the header and footer while I typeset my file? I have all the correct file paths for the input commands. Also, there is no error detected by my typesetting tools. I can't find a reason my document cannot display a header and a footer.

I'm using Texpad 1.8.7 on a MacOS Mojave 10.14.6. I've installed the full version of the MacTeX and I have double checked that I have the `fancyhdr` package installed in the right place. Can anyone help?

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {/Users/siyang/Desktop/Images/} }
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
**\usepackage{fancyhdr}**
**\pagestyle{fancy}**

\title{
{Social Strain and Delinquency}\\
{\large The University}
}
\author{me}
\date{January 1, 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter*{Abstract}
Abstract goes here

\chapter*{Dedication}
Dedication goes here

\chapter*{Declaration}
I declare that..

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
I want to thank...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make sure your MWE is self contained, this MWE currently is referencing files we do not have access to.

Comment: Are you aware that the first page of a chapter will get no header while all following pages will?

Comment: I have deleted the parts of the code that involves WME, but still no header or footer is shown on screen after typesetting. Can anyone further help me on this issue?

Comment: As @leandriis said, the first page of a `\chapter` is typeset in the `plain` style.